# JavaScript: Need Help accessing API JSON data

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to extract JSON data from an api, but running into issues. When I console.log the data, it shows...

[image]

I am trying to access name from the returned json object.I tried to log json.(whatever) from the object and is shows undefined.

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
           const response = await fetch('http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/')
           const json = response.json();
           console.log(json);
        }
    
fetchData();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await `response.json` as well.

So it should look like this

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
       const response = await fetch('http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/')
       const json = await response.json();
       console.log(json);
    }

fetchData();
```